# Boolean expressions in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In this line of code:

```
<p>{{ data.length > 0 && 'My data' || 'No data' }}</p>
```

what does the && and || mean?

At first I thought that these were boolean functions. The equivalent in Java or C# would be an inline IF statement:

```
<p>{{ data.length > 0 ? 'My data' : 'No data' }}</p>
```

But that statement doesn't work in AngularJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second statement actually does work in the new angularjs, the first one was just a workaround before it was implemented.

The && and || function exactly the same as the do an if statement. So you can use that outside of angular as well. Just like this:

```
console.log(4 > 3 && 'true' || 'false');
```

Comment: Except that in most programming languages && means AND and || means OR.

Comment: You're right about the inline IF statement. I updated my AngularJS library and it works.

Comment: It still does mean that in javascript. If(4 > 5 && 2 > 1 || 3 > 1) is completely valid